Possible Limitation in IIS 10 - applicationHost.config
Currently, I'm facing the following problem with IIS 10: when adding a new site in IIS 10, it shows the following error: 0x800710D8. All 100 sites are defined in the applicationHost.config file. When I remove one of the sites and then add a new one, the operation runs without error. However, when attempting to add another one, it shows the same error.
It seems like we might be hitting a limit. I've tried a registry tweak: MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB. I added it to the registry, but it did not work:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Configuration\MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\InetStp\Configuration\MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
Following has been tried:

Tried to use configSource to get a smaller file, this wont work for applicationHost.config
Adding the earlier mentioned registery keys:
Change of permissions
Using Procmon to log for any permission of read errors.


"Well, after a long search due to errors that are not directly related to the actual case, finally the solution is found:
dynamicRegistrationThreshold 
There is a setting called dynamicRegistrationThreshold which limits the total number of websites. For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/weblimits#how-to-configure-the-lower-limit-of-dynamic-site-activation
